# How can I translate this Kotlin code using zip() and lambda functions to Rust without the explicit "for" loops?

Tags: kotlin, rust

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val nomi = listOf("Lino", "Pino", "Bino")
    val cognomi = listOf("Rossi", "Bianchi", "Verdi")
    val titolo = "Dott."

    val combo = nomi.zip(cognomi) { n, c -> "$titolo $n $c" }
    combo.forEach { println(it) }
}
```

I am trying to translate this code from Kotlin to Rust. I can't figure out how to use zip() and lambda functions in a simple way like in Kotlin.

Is there a way to do this without `for` loops?

```rust
fn main() {
    let nomi = vec!("Lino", "Pino", "Bino");
    let cognomi = vec!("Rossi", "Bianchi", "Verdi");
    let titolo = "Dott.";

    let mut vec = Vec::new();

    for ((i,x),(j,y)) in nomi.iter().enumerate().zip(cognomi.iter().enumerate()) {
        let s = ("{} {} {}", titolo, x, y);
        vec.push(s)
    }

    for i in 0..vec.len() {
        println!("{} {} {}", vec[i].1, vec[i].2, vec[i].3)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Emanuele, usually you would need to provide an example of your specific problem (meaning that you have to try to implement it yourself first). Try to create the program in rust, and split the problems you encounter one by one. Then we can help you understand those problems.

Comment: John, thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. They key is to use `map()` and [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) as a replacement for the first for loop, and use [`for_each()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each) for the second loop:

```rust
fn main() {
    let nomi = vec!["Lino", "Pino", "Bino"];
    let cognomi = vec!["Rossi", "Bianchi", "Verdi"];
    let titolo = "Dott.";

    let vec = nomi
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .zip(cognomi.iter().enumerate())
        .map(|((i, x), (j, y))| ("{} {} {}", titolo, x, y))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    vec.iter()
        .for_each(|item| println!("{} {} {}", vec[i].1, vec[i].2, vec[i].3));
}
```

(Note that I replaced the parentheses in `vec!` with brackets; this is the recommended style and rustfmt does that automatically).

But in Rust, when we just iterate over a collection we prefer `for` loops over callback-style `for_each()`. If you do not want to move the `Vec`, you can iterate over `vec.iter()` or `&vec`:

```rust
for item in &vec {
    println!("{} {} {}", item.1, item.2, item.3)
}
```